# How can I publish PIL image binary through ROS without OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, ros, rospy

I'm currently trying to write a ROS Publisher/Subscriber setup that passes image binary opened by PIL. I'd like to not have to use OpenCV due to operating restrictions, and I was wondering if there was a way to do so. This is my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from PIL import Image
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image as sensorImage
from rospy.numpy_msg import numpy_msg
import numpy

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('image_stream', numpy_msg(sensorImage), queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('image_publisher', anonymous=False)
    rate = rospy.Rate(0.5)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        im = numpy.array(Image.open('test.jpg'))
        pub.publish(im)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__'
    try:
        talker()
    except ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

which on pub.publish(im) attempt throws:

```
TypeError: Invalid number of arguments, args should be ['header', 'height', 'width', 'encoding', 'is_bigendian', 'step', 'data'] args are (array([[[***array data here***]]], dtype=uint8),)
```

How would I transform the image into the right form, or is there a conversion method/different message type that supports just sending raw binary over the ROS connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed [Mark Setchell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64375418/5885566) works perfectly (ignoring the alpha channel in this example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import urllib2  # for downloading an example image
from PIL import Image
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image as SensorImage
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/image', SensorImage, queue_size=10)

    rospy.init_node('image_publisher')

    im = Image.open(urllib2.urlopen('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png'))
    im = im.convert('RGB')

    msg = SensorImage()
    msg.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    msg.height = im.height
    msg.width = im.width
    msg.encoding = "rgb8"
    msg.is_bigendian = False
    msg.step = 3 * im.width
    msg.data = np.array(im).tobytes()
    pub.publish(msg)
```

Comment: Ahh, cool - excellent! Thank you for sharing a more complete way of doing it.

Comment: Am I pushing my luck if I ask if there's a way of writing something in Python that sits around waiting to receive this message and saves it in a file when it arrives? I mean just on my Mac - I don't have a broker or hub or anything else running ROS.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question right... you have a system running ROS and publishing the image there and now you want to subscribe to it and save it on the same machine or at least in the same network? That'd just be a normal ROS subscriber listening to the topic (`/image` in my example)... (Across multiple machines in the same net just make sure to specify the same `ROS_MASTER_URI`)

Comment: No, I didn't ask the original question, I just gave an answer with some ideas about how to send an image in ROS. I have no ROS hardware/system here and no clue whatsoever about ROS. I just wondered if I could have some little Python script running on my Mac waiting to receive the image we have managed to send. That's all. It may be a silly question. I may need a ROS master node and special cables but I know nothing about ROS. Thank you though if you know how I could receive the image we sent.

Comment: @F1iX thanks for the solution, it publishes properly now. how would i go about reading the np.array(im).tobytes() back to another pil image on the other side? I tried to Image.open(msg.data) but it threw some errors, presumably due to the np.array().tobytes() conversion.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, use the rospy library and write a subscriber that sits and waits for messages, it uses a callback function on receiving a message to do processing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about ROS, but I use **PIL** a lot, so if someone else knows better, please ping me and I will delete this *"best guess"* answer.

So, it seems you need to make something like [this](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) from a `PIL Image`. So you need:

- 'header',
- 'height',
- 'width',
- 'encoding',
- 'is_bigendian',
- 'step',
- 'data'

So, assuming you do this:

```
im = Image.open('test.jpg')
```

you should be able to use:

- something you'll need to work out
- `im.height` from `PIL Image`
- `im.width` from `PIL Image`
- probably `const std::string RGB8 = "rgb8"`
- probably irrelevant because data is 8-bit
- probably `im.width * 3` as it's 3 bytes per pixel RGB
- `np.array(im).tobytes()`

Before anyone marks this answer down, nobody said answers have to be complete - they can just be *"hopefully helpful"*!

Note that if your input image is PNG format, you should check `im.mode` and if it is `"P"` (i.e. palette mode) immediately run:

```
im = im.convert('RGB')
```

to make sure it is 3-channel RGB.

Note that if your input image is PNG format and contains an alpha channel, you should change the `encoding` to `"rgba8"` and set `step = im.width * 4`.

Comment: Found code for `OpenCV-ROS Bridge` which may have useful ideas in it... https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/blob/noetic/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp